# Trying to have main menu and submenu classes

Tags: java, android

So my original problem was that in my manifest my menu wasent loading ie

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.MAINMENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

This was fixed by loading it at startup ie

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

So now my main menu works. However, the buttons inside MainMenu.xml will take you to another .xml file with more buttons. So now I have the same problem. I created another class called SubMenuChapter3 and put it in the manifest as such.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SubMenuChapter3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.SUBMENUCHAPTER3" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Now this doesnt work I am assuming for the same reason as before with mainmenu. Doesnt crash or give me errors. It just wont open the submenuchapter3 class. I forced the submenuchapter3 class to open by putting

```
 startActivity(new Intent("com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.SUBMENUCHAPTER3"));
```

directly into the MainMenu class outside of an onclick just to see if it was working. When I do that it opens the chapter_3.xml like it is supposed to and the button works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood `<intent-filter>` tag and the way you start activities.

Also maintain proper terminology - `Menu` and `Activity` are completely different things.

Everything you need to know about Activities can be found here: [Activities | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

**Example:**

This entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` says "show the `MainMenu` Activity as icon in the launcher":

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainMenu"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

EDIT: This allows Android to start `MainActivity`. It will also show in the installed app list.

The following Activity will not be displayed in launcher but can be opened from the app:

```
<activity android:name=".SubMenuChapter3"/>
```

EDIT: This allows Android to start `SubMenuChapter3`. It won't show in the installed app list.

These lines say "open the `SubMenuChapter3` Activity":

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SubMenuChapter3.class);
startActivity(i);
```

EDIT: You call this code from inside the `onClick` method inside `MainMenu`. It will launch `SubMenuChapter3`.

Comment: Its all confusing to me. Do you know where there is an example of what I am trying to do so I can maybe dissect it to better understand it?

Comment: You are trying to open one activity from another, right? See the edits, then [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity) might help you.

Comment: I figured it out thanks a lot for the help =) Something that helped is I got a pen and paper and drew a flow chart for the code. Once I did that it just clicked where I should put the intent to start the submenu which was in the class that the mainmenu called. Did that and now it works great.